# Make Parent div draggable with Child div

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How can I make a parent div draggable with a child div?

I'm using the jquery-ui draggable function for this. I cannot find anything regarding my problem on the site, so I'm asking here.

The whole div should only be draggable with it's header and not the whole div.

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

My Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/3xdLtask/1/

```
<div class="draggable window">
  <div class="windowHeader">
    <div class="windowTitle">
      child header
    </div>
    <div class="windowCloseBtn">
      <div class="windowCloseBtnInner">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="windowContent">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: DO NOT share to external sites. but instead create a working snippet 
( or fiddle ) to reproduce your problem

Comment: you want to drag this modal box layout  only with header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `handle event` for getting the desired result. Check the api documentation here.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#handle

> Here is an working example below:

```js
$("#MainDiv").draggable({
  handle: "#header"
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ModalBox {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.Modal-header {
  background: #7bd4ff;
  width: 100$;
  height: 40px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.Modal-Body {
  height: 260px;
  background: #ffadc9;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ModalBox" id="MainDiv">
  <div class="Modal-header" id="header">I am Dragabble header !</div>
  <div class="Modal-Body">
    I am child ! I am Child ! I am Child ! I am child ! I am Child ! I am Child ! I am child ! I am Child ! I am Child ! I am child ! I am Child ! I am Child ! I am child ! I am Child ! I am Child ! I am child ! I am Child ! I am Child ! I am child ! I am    Child ! I am Child ! I am child !
  </div>

</div>
```